# How to prevent data loss when Front End hangs?

Tags: front-end

I wanted to add some custom line-styling to a plot and evaluated something like this:

```
(* SAVE ALL YOUR WORK BEFORE EVALUATING THIS *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteDashing[0.0015]]
```

Is there any way to stop such evaluation or recover my unsaved work?

I have tried standard keyboard shortcuts, but they don't work. I have also terminated all `WolframKernel` processes, but the Front End still doesn't respond.

Are there some best practices to prevent data loss when working with the Front End? Online version of Mathematica seems to have autosave functionality, but desktop version still requires periodic manual saving.

I use Mathematica 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)

Comment: No hang on Win7 x64, but there is significant slowdown due to `PlotStyle -> AbsoluteDashing[0.0015]` (Mathematica 12.0.0).

Comment: You can turn on notebook autosaving. There's a front-end option for it.